# Get week and day from days

Tags: php, laravel, date

I have a number of days let's say 20 days

I want function to return array of week number and the day of the week.

Current implementation and the problem:

```
function weekAndDayNumberFromDays($days)
{

    $week = (int) floor($days / 7);
    $dayRemainder = $days % 7;

    return [
        'week' => $week,
        'day' => $dayRemainder
    ];
}
```

Call

```
   foreach (range(1, 20) as $day) {
        dump("Day #" . $day, weekAndDayNumberFromDays($day));
    }
```

Output

> "Day #1"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 0   "day" => 1 ]
>
> "Day #2"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 0   "day" => 2 ]
>
> "Day #3"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 0   "day" => 3 ]
>
> "Day #4"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 0   "day" => 4 ]
>
> "Day #5"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 0   "day" => 5 ]
>
> "Day #6"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 0   "day" => 6 ]
>
> "Day #7"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 1   "day" => 0 ]
>
> "Day #8"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 1   "day" => 1 ]
>
> "Day #9"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 1   "day" => 2 ]
>
> "Day #10"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 1   "day" => 3 ]
>
> "Day #11"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 1   "day" => 4 ]
>
> "Day #12"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 1   "day" => 5 ]
>
> "Day #13"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 1   "day" => 6 ]
>
> "Day #14"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 2   "day" => 0 ]
>
> "Day #15"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 2   "day" => 1 ]
>
> "Day #16"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 2   "day" => 2 ]
>
> "Day #17"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 2   "day" => 3 ]
>
> "Day #18"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 2   "day" => 4 ]
>
> "Day #19"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 2   "day" => 5 ]
>
> "Day #20"
>
> array:2 [▼   "week" => 2   "day" => 6 ]

I want to print e.g. "Week 1, Day1", "week 3, Day 5" without "Week 0 or Day 0".

Comment: Can’t tell what the actual problem is supposed to be here. _“I tried to add 1 to $week and $dayRemainder”_ - and what about that failed, exactly? (Adding one to the day seems to make rather little sense though.)

Comment: @CBroe well, first week has number 0 instead of 1 and last day of week is 0 instead of 7 (while first day is still 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 7 days in a week. (of course)

You're moving the last day of a week to the next week doing `$days % 7`, if day is 7, `7 % 7 == 0`

```
1 % 7 == 1
2 % 7 == 2
...
7 % 7 == 0
```

So, removing 1 day keeps the last day of the week into the current one :

```
0 % 7 == 0
1 % 7 == 1
...
6 % 7 == 6
```

This result can be incremented to have the first day as 1, the second as 2... the 7th as 7

You've been right about adding 1 to the weeks, or simply calling `ceil()`, as stated in [Donkarnash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64984894/8398549) :

```
function weekAndDayNumberFromDays($days)
{
    $days--;
    $week = floor($days / 7) + 1;
    $dayRemainder = ($days % 7) + 1;

    return [
        'week' => $week,
        'day' => $dayRemainder
    ];
}

foreach (range(1, 20) as $day) {
    $arr = weekAndDayNumberFromDays($day);
    echo "Day #$day : week {$arr['week']}, day {$arr['day']}" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output :

```
Day #1 : week 1, day 1
Day #2 : week 1, day 2
Day #3 : week 1, day 3
Day #4 : week 1, day 4
Day #5 : week 1, day 5
Day #6 : week 1, day 6
Day #7 : week 1, day 7
Day #8 : week 2, day 1
Day #9 : week 2, day 2
Day #10 : week 2, day 3
Day #11 : week 2, day 4
Day #12 : week 2, day 5
Day #13 : week 2, day 6
Day #14 : week 2, day 7
Day #15 : week 3, day 1
Day #16 : week 3, day 2
Day #17 : week 3, day 3
Day #18 : week 3, day 4
Day #19 : week 3, day 5
Day #20 : week 3, day 6
```

Comment: Using `ceil` instead of `floor` also yields the same output

Comment: @Donkarnash yeah, probably, I didn't look there

Comment: Thanks for answering, but could you please elaborate more on this?

I still dont understand this and it sucks.

Comment: @Donkarnash can't use `ceil()` in my function, since I'm decrementing `$days`. if day is 1, `ceil(0 / 7) == 0`

Comment: Thanks, @Donkarnash, for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ceil` instead of floor

```php
function weekAndDayNumberFromDays($days)
{

    $week = (int) ceil($days / 7);
    $dayRemainder = $days % 7;

    return [
        'week' => $week,
        'day' => $dayRemainder
    ];
}
```